# ${path.separator} in Maven on Mac is set to ":"

Tags: maven, properties, pom.xml

We have a problem with several people using Windows and Maven, and I suspect the issue is with the `${path.separator}`. They get an error that a directory "D:\basedir\target/dist" does not exist. We don't get this error on Mac, Linux, and Unix systems.

I'd like to change this to be `${project.build.directory}${path.separator}dist`, but on a Mac, the value of `${path.separator}` is `:` and not `/`. Now my build is failing on Macs because `/Users/david/project/target:dist` isn't a valid directory.

How can I set my default `${path.separator}` on the Mac to be `/`?

Comment: Always use forward-slashes. For Maven builds on Windows, `${project.build.directory}/dist` works just fine (I work on Windows and use forward slashes everytime without issues), so maybe you have a problem elsewhere, not Maven related. Could you post a [mcve]?

Comment: Do not use `$[path.separator}` simply use a "/" Furthermore a path.separator is the separator for several paths for example in the PATH variable which you should not need there... Furthermore path.separator on Windows is ";"...Why do you need a dist folder in target ? which you need to define somehow?

Comment: Path separator is what goes between paths, not between path segments, no?

Comment: Yup, that explains everything. I want `${file.separator}` and not `${path.separator}`. On the old Mac System 9, the file separator was `:` which made me think it was a Mac issue. I *should* be able to use forward slashes without any problems, and it *should* work on Windows. Unfortunately, it doesn't. It could be a problem with a plugin I'm using? Let me try `${file.separator}` and see if that helps.

Comment: Yeah, my bad. It's `${file.separator}` I want and not `${path.separator}`. I've always used forward slashes before as my directory name separators, and I never had an issue before. This one project is a problem. I have a MacBook and I build on Linux systems. I have no problems with this one project. However, our Windows devs do. And, it's only this one project. I think it's a bug in [maven-frontend-plugin](https://github.com/eirslett/frontend-maven-plugin]).

Answer (score 19):

Just to close this out...

I wanted `${file.separator}` and not `${path.separator}`. `${path.separator}` is what is used to separate directory names in paths. On Windows, it's `;` and on Mac and Unix, it's `:`.

`${file.separator}` is the directory separator mark. On Windows, it's `\` and on Unix and Macs it's `/'.

I got confused because on the older System X Macs, the file separator was `:`. I normally just use `/`, but in this one project, that didn't work.